# Android possible to play youtube api inside dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, youtube-api

so far the youtube Api can be played inside `YouTubeBaseActivity` only

is there to anyway to make it work inside custom `dialog` ?

Comment: When i tried this (YouTube in a dialog) it gave me "Not Activity" Exception)

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment)? But: Note that while videos are playing, this View has a minimum size of 200x110 dp.

Comment: you can't play it without `YouTubeBaseActivity` there must be a way to play the video in Dialog right ?